# List of Gamma Ray Spectrum Values

Tags: spectroscopy, gamma-rays

I am trying to identify the peak which is occurring in my caesium 137 spectroscopy graph, and trying to find a creditable source with a list of most if not all gamma decay spectrum values for all elements, yet I am not sure that it exist.

If one dose is there a possibility someone could link im in the right direction, or maybe give me an idea to what is causing the pick in my graph.

[image]

Just to clarify it the point (62.4) I am trying to find.

Comment: Gamma radiation is normally a property of the isotope, not of the element. (But in your case, what you're seeing is actually a K-shell x-ray, not a nuclear gamma.)

Comment: It won't cover gamma ray spectra coming from nuclear transitions, but if you want x-ray transitions like the one here, the X-ray Transition Energies database linked [in this NIST listing](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-databases) is probably the place to go for a wider list of spectra.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ,Thank you very much for the advice and info

Comment: @BenCrowell And Thank you for you input too much appreciated

Comment: Some additional resources which might be useful: [one](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_2/4_2_1.html), [two](http://henke.lbl.gov/optical_constants/), [three](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=other&book=air&page=Ciddor), [four](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Xcom/html/xcom1.html), [five](https://vuo.elettra.eu/services/elements/WebElements.html), [six](http://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/Sec_1-1.html) (with a hat-tip to Daniel Rivas, from whom I stole this list).

Comment: There is also http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/ . Mainly for gammas, but it also lists relevant x-rays. (And there may also be fluorescence from the shielding.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably not find this peak in your gamma ray catalogue because it’s an X-ray peak.

Photoelectric absorption in the materials surrounding the detector (i.e. usually the shielding material) can lead to generation of a characteristic X-ray that can reach the detector, especially if the atomic number of the material is high.

In this case, it looks like a characteristic X-ray peak for lead (Pb). However, that depends on the precision of your energy calibration in this range. You might want to check the materials used in the detector, its shielding, and the source itself.